# Handling Progress Dialog in asynchronous events

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my android application, there is a situation where multiple asynchronous events happen at the same time and need to show a progress bar when such events happen. For example, user clicked a button to download a file from internet. An async task is spawned and a progress dialog (As a dialog fragment) is shown. Lets say user rotated the screen and in the oncreate there is another async task which loads a file from disk in another async task and also needs to a progress dialog. I end up in a situation where there are multiple progress bars appear one over other and gives a bad UI experience. Is there a way to have a shared progress dialog manager kind of implementation in the framework which takes care of these kind if scenarios

Any help is appreciated.